# Dropzone.js how to change config settings on the fly

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dropzone.js

I'm using [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to handle file uploads for my web app. I'm trying to figure out the best way to change certain config settings in response to events. One option is to destroy and recreate the Dropzone object, but it seems like there must be a less awkward way to do it. In particular, I'd like to temporarily disable "the dropzone" once image files have started loading.